# Java create bat file and escape spaces

Tags: java, batch-file

My app is creating a `.bat` file in the users `Startup` directory to be able to auto run when the users logs in.

This is how i am currently creating the `.bat`:

```
File startupFile=getStartupFile();
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(startupFile));
out.println("@echo off");
out.println("start " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + fileSeparator +"MyApp.exe");
out.println("exit");
out.close();
}
```

Btw: `startupFile` is just the location to the `Startup` directory

The problem seems to be that sometimes the `System.getProperty("user.dir")` contains spaces in the path. For example the second line can be:

```
start C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyApp.exe
```

And this breaks the `.bat` file when it tries to find the application to run.

Any ideas how i can make the `.bat` understand where to find the application? No matter where its been installed?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the file location in every case (with or without space) should work

```
out.println("start \"" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + fileSeparator +"MyApp.exe\"");
```

Comment: @Alosyius What does your `MyApp.exe` do?

Comment: Its a java executable that is packed to an .exe with launch4j

Comment: @Alosyius I mean does it have visual side effects?

Comment: Not sure i follow what you mean, all i want is for the `.bat` to start the `.exe`

Comment: @Alosyius If it opened a cmd window, it seems like it did.

Comment: Yea it opened a cmd window but nothing happends

Comment: @Alosyius I would go review if the `.exe` actually does what you think it should be doing.